# updating a column, based on a condition returning itself or another column value

Tags: pandas

I have spent 4 hours trying to solve this problem and cannot get it working. I have nowhere to turn, any help would be most appreciated.

I have

- a column called tdf["current"]
- for any row with tdf["current"] == "£ 0.00"
- I need to replace tdf["current"] with that rows *tdf["old"]* value

**Attempt 1**

```
tdf['currrent'] = tdf['currrent'].apply(lambda x: tdf['old'] if x == "£ 0.00" else tdf['currrent'])
```

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

**Attempt 2**

```
for idx, row in tdf.iterrows():
    row['current'] = row['current'].apply(lambda x: row['old'] if x == "£ 0.00" else row['current'])
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'apply'

**Attempt 3**

```
for x in range(int(tdf.shape[0])):
    if tdf["old"].values[x] == "£ 0.00":
        print(tdf.at[tdf.index[x], "old"])
```

> ```
> This returns duplicate rows for the total df size, for each row, this is pretty broken, I gave up on this route
> ```

**Attempt 4**
Getting lost in my head now

```
for x in range(int(tdf.shape[0])):
    if tdf["old"].values[x] == "£ 0.00":
        print(tdf.at[tdf.index[x], "old"])
    else:
        print(False)
```

> This looked like it was going to work, it runs for False, when it reaches truthy
> ValueError: Invalid call for scalar access (getting)!

**Attempt 5 and beyond**

Variations of loops and using .loc[] and .at[]

Comment: please provide the input dataframe and the expected output (as **text**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely on the description, it looks like you could use `mask` (or `where`):

`tdf["current"]= tdf["current"].mask(tdf["current"].eq("£ 0.00"), tdf["old"])`

*NB. with pandas, you often want to avoid loops and `apply`, for most tasks, there is likely an efficient way to do it without loops.*

Comment: that is amazing! that worked in my notebook instantly. You are a life saver!

Comment: @dimButTries this is actually pretty basic pandas ;) but glad it helped!